# How to acquire lock on a table and not let other transaction get read access?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, locking

I am having a nodejs program which uses sequelize to create tables and insert data based on it.

Now, in future we are going to have multiple instances of the program and so we don't want multiple instances to read from the table during program startup so that only one instance can do the setup thing if required and other instance shouldn't get 'any access' to the table until the first instance has completed it's work.

I have checked 'transaction locking' - *shared* and *exclusive* but both of them seems to be giving reading access to the tables which I don't want.

**My requirement is** specifically that once a transaction acquires lock on a table, other transaction shouldn't be able to read from that table unless first one has completed it's work. How can I do this?

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags. Only tag the **one** DBMS you're really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-lock.html) the statement to lock a table is, `LOCK TABLE ...`

If you lock a table in exclusive mode, then no other access is allowed - not even a SELECT. Exclusive mode is the default:

> If no lock mode is specified, then ACCESS EXCLUSIVE, the most restrictive mode, is used.

The manual [explains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) the different lock modes:

> ACCESS EXCLUSIVE
>
> This mode guarantees that the holder is the only transaction accessing the table in any way.

Comment: In sequelize any idea what should be the command to lock transaction in exclusive mode?

Comment: `LOCK TABLE the_table`

Comment: I have a transaction already created in sequelize, I want to lock it using exclusive mode. If I have to use LOCK TABLE the_table, then that would be in literals. Isn't there any way to put exclusive in transanction object in sequelize?

Comment: To lock the table you will need to run that SQL - how you do that depends on the library you are using. But I don't know Sequelize, but I would be surprised if there wasn't a way to run a "raw" SQL statement.

Comment: ok! I will check it! Thanks for the help, really appreciate.
In case some sequelize expert is checking this out, please do let me know how to lock table using transaction so that other transactions can't read the same table.

Comment: + Also I know how to do using raw query, it's just that the project is using transaction and there is a way to use lock in the same transaction. The only point it how to make the lock exclusive so that other transaction can't use the same table in any way.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL use [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) to lock an entire table.

In postgresql `LOCK TABLE whatever IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;` does the trick.

For best results have your app, when starting, look for a particular table. Do something simple and fast such as `SELECT id FROM whatever LIMIT 1;` to probe whether the table exists. If your app gets an exception because the table isn't there, then do

```sql
CREATE TABLE whatever ....;
LOCK TABLES whatever WRITE;
```

from the app creating the table. It blocks access to the table from all instances of your app except the one that gets the LOCK.

Once your table is locked, the initial `SELECT` I suggested will block from other clients.  There's a possible race condition if two clients try to create the table more-or-less concurrently. But the extra CREATE TABLE will throw an exception.

Note: if you LOCK more than one table, and it's possible to run the code from more than one instance of the app, always always lock the tables in the same order, or you have the potential for a deadlock.

Comment: Will this work on postgres? I am using postgres for this. Also, I didn't understand "LOCK TABLES whatever WRITE;" -> is this complete command?